# plupload asp.net handler incomplete files

Tags: jquery, asp.net, handler, ashx, plupload

When i set runtimes to "html4" everything works perfectly. All the other runtimes (which are better because you can select multiple files at one time) seem to work fine to, except that the files are not completely uploaded. After a few kb (42 / 28 / 50) it says '100% completed'. The files are stored and are incomplete. Any ideas?

```
$("#uploader").plupload({
// General settings
runtimes : 'gears,flash,silverlight,browserplus,html5',
url : 'upload.ashx',
max_file_size : '10mb',
chunk_size : '1mb',
unique_names : true,

// Resize images on clientside if we can
resize : {width : 320, height : 240, quality : 90},

// Specify what files to browse for
filters : [
    {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
{title : "Zip files", extensions : "zip"}
    ],

    // Flash settings
    flash_swf_url : 'js/plupload.flash.swf',

    // Silverlight settings
    silverlight_xap_url : 'js/plupload.silverlight.xap'
});

// Client side form validation
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    var uploader = $('#uploader').plupload('getUploader');

    // Files in queue upload them first
    if (uploader.files.length > 0) {
        // When all files are uploaded submit form
        uploader.bind('StateChanged', function() {
            if (uploader.files.length === (uploader.total.uploaded + uploader.total.failed)) {
                $('form')[0].submit();
            }
        });

        uploader.start();
    } else
        alert('You must at least upload one file.');

    return false;
});
```

upload.ashx:

Public Class upload : Implements IHttpHandler

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    Dim chunk As Integer = If(context.Request("chunk") IsNot Nothing, Integer.Parse(context.Request("chunk")), 0)
    Dim fileName As String = If(context.Request("name") IsNot Nothing, context.Request("name"), String.Empty)

    Dim fileUpload As HttpPostedFile = context.Request.Files(0)

    Dim uploadPath = context.Server.MapPath("uploads")
    Using fs = New FileStream(Path.Combine(uploadPath, fileName), If(chunk = 0, FileMode.Create, FileMode.Append))
        Dim buffer = New Byte(fileUpload.InputStream.Length - 1) {}
        fileUpload.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)

        fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
    End Using

    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
    context.Response.Write("Success")
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: Does it change anything if your replace fileUpload.InputStream.Length with fileUpload.ContentLength ?